# require throw an error when the file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load some js files by dynamic path using require

```
 try {    
  require([`views/Report/${path}/filterProps.js`], function(data) {
    console.log(props);       
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

the path is a usual string (for instance 'file1')

everything is fine but when the file does not exist it thrown the error.
I have tried try-catch but it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea to solve the problem?

**update**
this how it worked for me:

```
 require.onError = function(err) {
        console.log(err);       
      };
require([`views/Report/${path}/filterProps.js`], function(data) {
        console.log(props);       
      });
```

Comment: Show us how you tried to use try-catch block please.

Comment: please add full code, where you defined `path`.

Comment: What `require` function is this? AMD?